# Notice: Undefined variable:at line 51

Tags: php

i am pretty new to PHP and self teaching so i know i will have some errors, can someone assist me in figuring out why i get this error? i believe i have defined the variabl...

Here is my code (sorry i did not know if i could attach so i just pasted)

```
<?php 
include ('dbconnect.php');
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>New User </title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="user"><p><a href="../DBindex.php">Log In</a> </p>
</div>

<center>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['cmdadd'])) {
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);
$emailaddress = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["emailaddress"]);
$address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["address"]);
$telephone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["telephone"]);
$country = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["country"]);

if(empty($username)){
$errors[]="Username Not Entered";
}
if(empty($password)){
$errors[]="Password Not Entered";
}
if(empty($emailaddress)){
$errors[]="Email Not Entered";
}
if(empty($telephone)){
$errors[]="PhoneNumber Not Entered";
}

if(empty($country)){
$errors[]= "Country Not Entered";
}
}

if(!empty($errors)){

foreach($errors as $error){
echo'<a href = "DBregistration.php"> REDO </a>'; 
echo $error."<br/>";

}
} 
else{
$query = "select * 
from users 
where username = '$username' ";

$result = mysql_query($query, $connection);

if (!$query) {
echo "<p>" . mysql_error () . "</p>";
}

$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($rows != 0 ) { ?>

<a href = "DBregistration.php"> Redo </a>

<?php
}
else {
$query = "insert into users
values              ('$username','$password','$emailaddress','$address','$telephone','$country')";

mysql_query ($query , $connection);

if (!$query) {
echo "<p>" . mysql_error() . "</p>";
}            
else { ?>

<?php

}  }
}
?>
```

Line 51 is:

```
where username = '$username' ";
```

Comment: And line 51 is the line – ?

Comment: wow.. are we supposed to count line 51 from the top ?

Comment: Just a note MYSQL: "This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0" - http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php . You can easily use MYSQLI.

Comment: Line 51 is `$username` in your sql query. Your `if(isset($_POST['cmdadd']))` statement is likely failing.

Comment: Try not to mix so much php and html code. It's more readable if you don't do that. I bet this can be written without so much mixing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 1):

The code you pasted contains no syntax errors. So that's your answer. I suspect the error is in some other file; you did not say *which* file the message came from. It could be that `dbconnect.php` is not setting `$connection`, I guess.

But since you say you're a beginner, I'll pass on some suggestions that I was given and have found useful. In no meaningful order:

1. Indent your code. Ideally, use a checker such as [CodeSniffer for PHP](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer/). Even better, use an IDE with embedded CodeSniffer support: PHPStorm, [Eclipse with PHP Developers Tools](https://eclipse.org/pdt/), etc. Some of those are free and well supported. You'll need some time to learn - but I can promise you'll never look back.
2. Use [PDO and prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of mysql_* functions. It makes **no sense** to start learning something that [is going to disappear](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) pretty soon.
3. Try and chop up your code in smaller units, [use functions whenever you can](http://pdepend.org/), and keep HTML text and data as separated as you possibly can. It looks a pain in the nether regions for the first week. Maintenance-wise, it's a really good habit. You might even be interested in looking at some [template systems](http://www.smarty.net/).
4. Always keep error reporting to maximum when developing. If errors, warnings, or notices *are* there, they won't go away. You can only choose whether it will be you who spots them first, or your users.
5. PHP error reporting and tracing leaves a lot to be desired. Tools that you'll want to install are [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) and, much later, PHPXHprof. XDebug also has step-by-step debugging support if you use a supported IDE such as Eclipse with PDT.
6. Some might think this smacks of "professional", and advise not to "waste time" on such frills, but - consider a [version control system](https://subversion.apache.org/). The first time, and this also I can promise you - *that time will come*, that you make some changes, "nothing works!", and you'll want to go back... or see what you changed, maybe compare the two versions... the time "wasted" in setting up a simple local repository will be revealed to have been very well invested indeed. Also, such tools are *also* integrated in most IDEs. Using them is as easy as right-clicking and selecting 'Highlight changes' or 'Compare to a previous version'.

Answer (score 0):

If I am counting correctly, it appears that the problem is in the line 
"$result = mysql_query($query, $connection); ?
I don't see the value of $connection set anywhere.

Comment: sorry guys i didnt realise there was no like counter. the line in question is 

$query = "select * 
from users 
where username = '$username' ";

if you scroll all the way down it should be close to the top

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem comes here :
`$query = "select * 
            from users 
            where username = '$username' ";`

because if the form is `$_POST['cmdadd'])` doesn't exist `$username` is not set so it's undefined

You need to launch the request with the $username only if the $_POST['cmdadd'] exist.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    <?php 
include ('dbconnect.php');
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>New User </title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="user"><p><a href="../DBindex.php">Log In</a> </p>
</div>

<center>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['cmdadd'])) {
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);
$emailaddress = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["emailaddress"]);
$address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["address"]);
$telephone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["telephone"]);
$country = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["country"]);

if(empty($username)){
$errors[]="Username Not Entered";
}
if(empty($password)){
$errors[]="Password Not Entered";
}
if(empty($emailaddress)){
$errors[]="Email Not Entered";
}
if(empty($telephone)){
$errors[]="PhoneNumber Not Entered";
}

if(empty($country)){
$errors[]= "Country Not Entered";
}


if(!empty($errors)){

foreach($errors as $error){
echo'<a href = "DBregistration.php"> REDO </a>'; 
echo $error."<br/>";

}
} 
else{
$query = "select * from users where username = '$username' ";

$result = mysql_query($query, $connection);

if (!$query) {
echo "<p>" . mysql_error () . "</p>";
}

$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($rows != 0 ) { ?>

<a href = "DBregistration.php"> Redo </a>

<?php
}
else {
$query = "insert into users
values              ('$username','$password','$emailaddress','$address','$telephone','$country')";

mysql_query ($query , $connection);

if (!$query) {
echo "<p>" . mysql_error() . "</p>";
}            
else { ?>

<?php

}  }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks Mohsendac, it fixed the undefined variable error, what exactly did you change?

Comment: just move '}' in line 38 to line 81. when you create scope with <?php ?> should consider that variables aren't global. I strongly recommend you clear your code.